# Box2d Collision not good enough

Tags: java, mobile, box2d, physics

in my game there are objects which falling from the sky
the objects collide with the hero (can move on x-axis)

the problem is that sometimes the objects kinda stuck/roll on the hero

what I want is a big/major hit..
which parameter of the fixtures/bodies I need to change in order to control the
force of the hit?

Comment: You need to describe this better - eg. what shape are the fixtures? If the hero is a square and the falling objects are circles, then naturally they will fall on the hero and roll. Making them collide faster to get a 'big hit' will not change that. If you want the falling objects to fall faster you can apply a downwards force to them. If you want them to bounce off you can set the restitution of their fixtures to a higher value.

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the mass of the bodies. This will increase they simulated wheight.

Comment: how you do it? didn't find a property "mass"

Comment: You sure have a `MassData` object that have the `mass` property.

Comment: that didn't help much though
got more tips for me? :)

Comment: the problem is the hero is a circle, and also the objects which falling.. so in some cases the objects kinda rolling on the hero..
that's the problem =/